# 1 to 5 / by 1 to 5 / from 1 to 5 / 1 untill 5...?

Tags: prepositions, numbers, range-inclusion

What prepositions should I use when I want to say about a range of numbers?

Example of use in a scene where each garden or car was numbered:

> There are beautiful flowers in the garden #3 to the garden #8.
>
> You must clean the cars three to five.

Comment: Please give an example of a sentence using the range

Comment: "there are beuatiful flowers by the garden#3 to the garden#8" (in a scene where each garden was numbered). thank you again ;)

Comment: In the gardens _3 to 8_ or _3 through 8_

Comment: great! thx ;)  might i give one more example? "you must clean the cars three to five" or "... through five". right? thank you

Comment: Please update your question instead of giving comments. you can use either.

Comment: sure,  thx for your tips ;) did i improve it? i've been accessing this site so long, but it was the first time i posted a question. i hope it will be better next time.  thx ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use this in a formal paper, in my opinion you should avoid writing numbers all together. If I were you I would like it like this:

Jack has been working from one to five.
Jack has worked from one o'clock until five o'clock.
Jack's shift is one to five, so he'll leave at five (this is informal).

It depends on where you say these but "by 1 to 5" is not a clause that can be relevantly used in your case.

Only in informal writing (writing an email to a close friend for example) you can use numbers or if it is a mathematical expression, then you can. In formal writing, we usually don't use numbers.

Comment: your answer was very useful! thx ;)